# How to control mesh curvature using an armature

Tags: armature

My goal is to make a curved Pillow Box model in blender starting from the flat die-line. The problem is that there seem to be no real accurate way to control the amount curve of the folding panel without using bevel modifier or something like that.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you merely want to model it or do you want to animate the folding process?

Comment: well,if it can be animated is better. But yes I want to fold it in the most "natural" way possible without starting from a cube and apply modifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a few objects for this...

Here is the objects involved
[image]

Pick one of the circle meshes as the target mesh.

Use the other three remaining circular meshes as the "theoretical children".

Apply the Copy Scale Constraint to all three of these children.
[image]

Use these settings for the constraint on all three children.

[image]

Arrange the mesh objects as shown.

[image]

Here's a demo of the magic.
[image]

---

**Appended The Working Blend File Using Drivers + Demo Animation of how to use it**

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: Only problem: the curve is a part of a circle, not half an ellipse

Comment: @Haunt_House great catch, I have adjusted the solution on this using drivers and I will post the blend immediately for study, and appended demo. soon after I will post the write-up

Comment: Looks promising. Let me take a while to digest the solution.